# Hadoop map/reduce sort

Tags: hadoop

I have a map-reduce job and I am using just the mapper because the output of each mapper will definitely have  a unique key. My question is when this job is run and I get the output files, which are like part-m-00000, part-m-00001 ... Will they be sorted in order of key?

Or Do I need to implement a reducer which does nothing but just writes them to files like part-r-00000, part-r-000001. And does these guarantee that the output is sorted  in the order of the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the keys within the file and make sure that the keys in the file are less than the keys in file j when i is less than j, you not only need to use a reducer, but also a partitioner. You might want to consider using something like Pig to do this as it will be trivial. If you want to do it with MR, use the sorted field as your key and write a partitioner to make sure that your keys end up in the correct reducer.

Comment: Ok. So the output of map is not sorted. When you say that I need to use a reducer, what does the reducer exactly do ? Can you suggest me some resources from where I can learn Pig.

Comment: Well, there is the pig manual: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html. There is also the pig book: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Pig-Alan-Gates/dp/1449302645/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1352935965&sr=8-3&keywords=pig+book For most tasks using pig or hive is just much easier.

Answer (score 0):

When your map function outputs the keys, it goes to the [partition function which does a sort](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html). Therefore by default the keys will be in sorted order and you can use the identity reducer.

Comment: I understand that the before the reducer funtion, all the outputs of maps are sorted. My question is if we have n reducers which produce n files, then will the n files be sorted as per the keys ?

Comment: Based on this map reduce book the reducers get the files in the sorted order http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf (page 27)

Comment: Yes that is correct. But do reducers produce output in sorted order ?

Comment: I can't find anything to confirm it but you can always send the result of the Reducer to the IdentityMapper and IdentityReducer. Essentially create a second job. Some of the results maybe sorted since there can be multiple map/reduce iterators but if the final reduce changes the order say input <a,z> and reducer outputs <z,a> i believe the order is not guaranteed then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee sorted order, you can simply use a single `IdentityReducer`.

If you want it to be more parallelizable, you can specify more reducers, but then the output will by default only be sorted within files, not across files. I.e., each file will be sorted, but part-r-00000 will not necessarily come before part-r-00001. If you DO want it to be sorted across files, you can use a custom partitioner that partitions based on the sorting order. I.E., reducer 0 gets all of the lowest keys, then reducer 1, ... and reducer N gets all of the highest keys.

Comment: When you say part-r-00000 will not necessarily come before part-r-00001. Does that mean that keys in part-r-00000 will always be less than keys in part-r-00001

Comment: right, for example, if you do not specify a custom sorting partitioner, then part-r-00000 might contain "1, 5, 6, 8, 10" and part-r-00001 might contain "2, 4, 7, 11".